# Good Digital Pen that Integrates with Microsoft OneNote

Tags: microsoft-onenote, hardware-rec, productivity

Does anyone know of a good digital pen product (like the Logitech IO2) that:

1. Can cleanly integrate with Microsoft OneNote
2. Works with regular paper (not expensive DPS paper)
3. Works with Windows 7 - ideally Win7 x64

Comment: wrt #2, are you aware that some DPS pens now allow you to [print your own dot paper](http://www.livescribe.com/en-gb/smartpen/dotpaper.html)? (requires access to 600dpi colour laser postscript printer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend Genius G-Note 7100.

It meets requirements 2 and 3, however not sure as I have never tried on point 1.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't integrate with OneNote out of the box, but there is a free, open-source importer utility available here: http://code.google.com/p/dnt-onenote-importer/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a Asus T91 tablet PC, both in 8 and 10 inches. full tablet/touch Pc running XP.